# PHP - Upload file to another server without curl

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

I have one question, can i upload file to another server without curl..
Because not every server have CURL ...
Thanks...

Comment: Whether the receiving server has cURL or not doesn't mean a thing. All that matters, is that the executing server has it. To answer your actual question: Technically yes, depending on which file transfer modes the remote server supports. Does it have FTP? (For example)

Comment: yes, it have ftp ...
can you answer my questions ...

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible using pure PHP fopen together with stream_context_create. The following example comes from the online PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php):

```
function do_post_request($url, $postdata, $files = null) 
{ 
    $data = ""; 
    $boundary = "---------------------".substr(md5(rand(0,32000)), 0, 10); 

    //Collect Postdata 
    foreach($postdata as $key => $val) 
    { 
        $data .= "--$boundary\n"; 
        $data .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"".$key."\"\n\n".$val."\n"; 
    } 

    $data .= "--$boundary\n"; 

    //Collect Filedata 
    foreach($files as $key => $file) 
    { 
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']); 

        $data .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$key}\"; filename=\"{$file['name']}\"\n"; 
        $data .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg\n"; 
        $data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n\n"; 
        $data .= $fileContents."\n"; 
        $data .= "--$boundary--\n"; 
    } 

    $params = array('http' => array( 
           'method' => 'POST', 
           'header' => 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary, 
           'content' => $data 
        )); 

   $ctx = stream_context_create($params); 
   $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx); 

   if (!$fp) { 
      throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg"); 
   } 

   $response = @stream_get_contents($fp); 
   if ($response === false) { 
      throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg"); 
   } 
   return $response; 
} 

//set data (in this example from post) 

//sample data 
$postdata = array( 
    'name' => $_POST['name'], 
    'age' => $_POST['age'], 
    'sex' => $_POST['sex'] 
); 

//sample image 
$files['image'] = $_FILES['image']; 

do_post_request("http://example.com", $postdata, $files);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use [ftp_put](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php):

```
define("LOCAL_FILE","PATH_TO_LOCAL_FILE");
define("FTP_ADDRESS","ftp.domain.com");
define("FTP_FILE","PATH_TO_REMOTE_FILE");
define("FTP_USERNAME","USERNAME");
define("FTP_PASSWORD","PASWORD");

$conn = ftp_connect(FTP_ADDRESS);
$login = ftp_login($conn, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
ftp_put($conn, FTP_FILE, LOCAL_FILE, FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn);
```

Whereas, the ftp domain would supply you with the location to the ftp file as well as the username and password.