# Copy images from one remote server to another remote server with PHP

Tags: php

```
public function foo_bar_testing()
{
         $upload_path = "uploads/";
         $newname = "image.jpg";
         $name= $_FILES['file']['name'];
         $type= $_FILES['file']['type'];
         $size= $_FILES['file']['size'];
         $tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];     
         $error=$_FILES['file']['error'];

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'./'.$upload_path.$newname);
        $newname=$newname.".".$ext;

            /////////////////////
            $conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.server.com');           
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'xyz@server.com', '****');

        $file = "http://**.**.**.**/folder/".$upload_path.$newname;
        $remote_file = "http://***.**.**.**/XYZ/".$upload_path.$newname;
        if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
         echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
        } else {
         echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
        }
        ftp_close($conn_id);
    }
```

hi , i am trying to copy the images uploaded onto a server to another remote server . Above is my code but i am confused as in how to do it . I want to create a back up of the images uploaded onto to current remote server and then copy them to the other remote server.

Thanks in advace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785433/php-upload-file-to-another-server-without-curl

Comment: i tried the code from the link . doesnt seem to work.